# Is it practical to develop an actual application using Assembly?

Tags: assembly, programming-languages, low-level

Assembly (as far as I know) is the most low level language there is. It communicates (again, as fair as I understand) directly with the hardware and memory.

Is it possible (even if takes very long) to develop an actual application (even if it's only a text-based console application) using Assembly? (An application that's more complex than Hello World). Has this ever been done? Or has Assembly only ever 'helped' to develop with more high-level languages such as C?

Comment: Assembler usually translates to _macro assembler_. That means, that there's already another level of language on top of assembler. In addition to that, every productive programmer pursuits in increasing the level of abstraction that describes the behavior of the program. That means programming both compile time and runtime languages (and interpreters) with all the available tools. The difference of the coding speed is in whether some other existing language already speaks your application.

Comment: Possible but not practical. Find the hotspots - the [90/10 rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#Bottlenecks) - then consider more efficient algorithms. If you *must* have that final performance boost that assembly may deliver, that can't be effectively encapsulated or exposed by the language / compiler, then it's worth considering. Will the steep learning curve, investment in time, unforgiving bugs, maintenance and portability issues be worth it? Will a 5% speedup eaten by Moore's law in a few months be worth it? ... Then again, some familiarity makes better programmers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Yes and No.

Assembly code is very low level because it directly mimics the instructions the hardware understands. There's yet another level deeper, which would be pure binary code, but that indeed nowadays nobody uses any more (it has been done in the beginning of computers, though). But there's nothing that prevents you from writing entire applications in assembly. In fact, a C compiler (or any other high-level compiler) will first translate the code to (some kind of) assembly before doing the final step to convert it to binary code. Some compilers even allow you to export the assembly code. There's nothing that would prevent you from writing that yourself.

Entire operating systems have been written using assembly. In fact, the only place where you really need assembly even nowadays is in the very core of an operating system, because there's practically no high-level support for the instructions that you need there.